# What resources do folks use for learning about Xcode templates?

Tags: iphone, xcode, templates

[image]I do a lot of prototyping and need more Xcode templates for the different classes of apps that I prototype. My current source of information for Xcode templates is a set of [links](http://delicious.com/iggymwangi/xcode+templates) from the web. What other resources do folks use for Xcode iPhone templates design and development?

Answer (score 1):

there are several resources on the web as you pointed out.

One of the most important things that I use are the `Xcode Templates Expansion Macros`, this are heavily used in Apple's templates, and can make your templates a lot better. [Here's](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/03/xcode-project-template-expansion-macros.html) a great tutorial and table that shows all the Xcode Template Macros and some ideas of how to use them.

You seem to have several pointers in your links to how to actually make the template, so I think this would be helpful for you.